# how to trigger an event when selection is changed with <datalist> tag?

Tags: html, node.js, angular

i want to add search option for selection in select tag. i tried with select but it wasnt working so i changed it with datalist search is added but the corresponding event is not getting triggered. is there solution? below is the snippet for  that i tried

```html
 <input style="margin: auto; 
                width: 150px;" type="text" name="setApp" list="ddApp" (blur)="validateInput($event)" placeholder="Search app" (change)="filterSetApps($event)" required ngDefaultControl>
                <datalist style="width: 100px;height: 100px;" id="ddApp" name="ddApp" [ngModel]="selectedAppId" (doubleClick)="appChange($event)">
                  <option  style="width: 100px;height: 100px;" *ngFor="let c of filteredApps" >{{c.appName}}</option>                 
                </datalist>
```

Comment: Though its not clear which event is not getting triggered. Try only with blur and check. Otherwise you can use template reference to get the input value like shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable)

Comment: appChange($event) this event is not getting triggered.